# Is there a commonly used notion of regular language outside of finite order types and $\omega$?

Tags: logic, order-theory, automata, regular-language, second-order-logic

There are correspondences between regular languages and finite automata, and $\omega$-regular languages and Buchi or Muller automata (as well as the characterisation in terms of the monadic second order logic of $\omega$).

But what about if we take words indexed by some or other fixed order type which is neither finite, nor equal to $\omega$, nor equal to $\omega^*$? For example take words to just be elements of $\Sigma^{\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ is some fixed linear order, say $\Sigma^{\omega+\omega^*}$ or $\Sigma^{\mathbb{Z}}$, with $\Sigma$ a finite alphabet.

If there is something that makes sense only for discrete linear orders $\alpha$ this would be fine, but ideally I am after something that works not just for well-orders (I am aware of Buchi's work on `transfinite automata recursions' in this direction).

Any references to literature would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. There are several papers on this topic, see the references of [1, 2, 4] for an extensive bibliography. Note also the extension to tree automata in [3].

[1] N. Bedon, A. Bès, O. Carton, and C. Rispal, [Logic and rational languages of words indexed by linear orderings](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/%7Ebedon/Recherche/Biblio/lrlwilo.pdf), *Theory Comput. Syst.* **46** (2010), no. 4, 737--760.

[2] V. Bruyère and O. Carton, [Automata on linear orderings](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00160925/document), *J. Comput. System Sci.*, 73(1):1–24, (2007).

[3] V. Bruyère, O. Carton, and G. Sénizergues, [Tree automata and automata on linear orderings](http://www.numdam.org/article/ITA_2009__43_2_321_0.pdf), *Theoret. Informatics and Applications* **43**, no. 2, pp. 321-338, 2009.

[4] O. Carton, T. Colcombet, G. Puppis. [Regular languages of words over countable linear orderings](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00161039/document), Automata, languages and programming. Part II, 125--136, LNCS 6756, Springer, Heidelberg, 2011.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is the kind of thing I was looking for.